# Oracle counting values in pivot clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

| ID | LOTYP | PROID | LOCKR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXXX | 06 | 01 | Y |
| XXXXX | 06 | 02 | X |
| XXXXX | 06 | 02 | S |
| XXXXX | 06 | 01 | R |
| XXXXX | 02 | 01 | Y |
| XXXXX | 02 | 02 | X |
| XXXXX | 02 | 02 | S |
| XXXXX | 02 | 01 | R |
| XXXXX | 02 | 01 | R |
| XXXXX | 02 | 01 | R |
| XXXXX | 02 | 01 | R |
| YYYYY | 06 | 01 | Y |
| YYYYY | 06 | 02 | X |
| YYYYY | 06 | 02 | S |
| YYYYY | 06 | 01 | R |
| YYYYY | 02 | 01 | Y |
| YYYYY | 02 | 02 | X |
| YYYYY | 02 | 02 | S |
| YYYYY | 02 | 01 | R |

If I run the below query, it gives the below

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT id,lotyp||proid As title,
           LISTAGG(lockr,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lotyp||proid) AS value
      FROM t
     GROUP BY id,lotyp||proid )
 PIVOT (
         MAX(value) FOR title IN ('0201' AS "0201",
                                  '0202' AS "0202",
                                  '0601' AS "0601",
                                  '0602' AS "0602"))   
 ORDER BY id;
```

| ID | 0201 | 0202 | 0601 | 0602 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXXX | R, R, R, R, Y | S, X | R, Y | S, X |
| YYYYY | R, Y | S, X | R, Y | S, X |

However, how could I obtain the below instead?

| ID | 0201 | 0202 | 0601 | 0602 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXXX | 4R, Y | S, X | R, Y | S, X |
| YYYYY | R, Y | S, X | R, Y | S, X |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count them first

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT id, title,
           LISTAGG(lockr,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY title) AS value
    FROM(
       SELECT id,lotyp||proid As title, case count(*) when 1 then '' else CAST(count(*) AS VARCHAR2(10)) end || LOCKR As LOCKR
       FROM  t
       GROUP BY id,lotyp||proid, LOCKR
   ) t
GROUP BY id, title )
PIVOT (
         MAX(value) FOR title IN ('0201' AS "0201",
                                  '0202' AS "0202",
                                  '0601' AS "0601",
                                  '0602' AS "0602"))   
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting Serg's accepted answer using CTEs instead of inline queries

```
WITH aux AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        lotyp || proid AS title,
        CASE COUNT(*)
                WHEN 1 THEN
                    ''
                ELSE
                    CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR2(10))
            END
        || lockr AS lockr
    FROM
        t
    GROUP BY
        id,
        lotyp || proid,
        lockr
), aux2 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        title,
        LISTAGG(lockr, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                title
        ) AS value
    FROM
        aux
    GROUP BY
        id,
        title
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    aux2 PIVOT (
        MAX ( value )
        FOR title
        IN ( '0201' AS "0201", '0204' AS "0204", '0209' AS "0209", '0210' AS "0210", '0601' AS "0601", '0602' AS "0602", '0603' AS
        "0603", '0604' AS "0604", '0605' AS "0605", '0609' AS "0609", '0610' AS "0610", '0612' AS "0612", '4101' AS "4101", '4102'
        AS "4102", '4105' AS "4105", '4112' AS "4112" )
    )
```